# prevent asking to use the microphone

Tags: swift, xcode, permissions, microphone

With the latest update (xcode 10.1 and iOS Mojave 10.14), the app I'm working on, which includes the Google Admob frameworks, has begun asking permission to use the microphone even though I am doing nothing with a microphone.

How do I prevent that pop-up from asking the user for permission every time the app is run?

Comment: Since I don't use it - and you've blamed it - stop using Google Admob? :-) Seriously, this is the danger of using third party frameworks. And if *indeed* this is where the issue lies, either fork it (if possible) or wait for Google to fix it.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203353
Seems like a bug of simulator.

Comment: @FrankChengthe link you posted points to Safari extension. Can you elaborate please how you know that this is a bug?

Comment: Fixed with Xcode 10.2 beta: it will only ask once.